# One of the identified items was in an invalid format

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm writing sqlhelper and my problem is:

When I try tolist, I get this error: "One of the identified items was in an invalid format".
  i tried SqlHandler.SetQueryableOrder(ret, sort, order).skip(1).take(1).ToList(),but the result wasn't what I wanted.

```
public List<T> PageListByQuery<T>(Expression<Func<T, bool>> query, string sort, string order, out int totalCount, int pageIndex = 0, int pageSize = 0, bool showCount = false) where T : class
{
    totalCount = 0;
    try
    {
        if (pageIndex <= 0 || pageSize <= 0)
        {
            _log.Error("pageIndex and pageSize more than 0");
            throw new Exception("pageIndex and pageSize more than 0");
        }
        using (_context = new MySqlContext())
        {
            //query's type is Expression<Func<T, bool>> query
            var ret = _context.Set<T>().Where(query);
            var res = SqlHandler.SetQueryableOrder(ret, sort, order);
            if (showCount)
            {
                totalCount = ret.Count();
            }
            return res.ToList();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        _log.Error("PageListByQuery method error:" + ex);
        throw;
    }
}
```

the SetQueryableOrder code :

```
public static IQueryable<T> SetQueryableOrder<T>(this IQueryable<T> query, string sort, string order)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(sort))
        throw new Exception("something!");

    PropertyInfo sortProperty = typeof(T).GetProperty(sort, BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.IgnoreCase);
    if (sortProperty == null)
        throw new Exception("something");

    ParameterExpression param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "t");
    Expression body = param;
    if (Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(body.Type) != null)
        body = Expression.Property(body, "Value");
    body = Expression.MakeMemberAccess(body, sortProperty);
    LambdaExpression keySelectorLambda = Expression.Lambda(body, param);

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(order))
        order = "ASC";
    string queryMethod = order.ToUpper() == "DESC" ? "OrderByDescending" : "OrderBy";
    query = query.Provider.CreateQuery<T>(Expression.Call(typeof(Queryable), queryMethod,
                                                       new Type[] { typeof(T), body.Type },
                                                       query.Expression,
                                                       Expression.Quote(keySelectorLambda)));
    return query.Skip(1).Take(1);
}
```

I don't know what the error is, please help.

Comment: i use mysql database and the sql look nomal in the sql log

Answer (score 2):

> The back-end representation of a GUID type was changed from BINARY(16)
> to CHAR(36). This was done to allow developers to use the server
> function UUID()  to populate a GUID table - UUID() generates a
> 36-character string. Developers of older applications can add 'Old
> Guids=true' to the connection string to use a GUID of data type
> BINARY(16).

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-8-0-connection-options.html

This error might come from the issue that the char(36) datatype field in Mysql stores non-GUID value.

Comment: The stack trace of the exception also might provide a clue, as e.g. in that case a call to 'GetGuid' should show up.

Answer (score 0):

in some case adding OldGuids=True; to connection string can solve the problem